# Jquery-find the end of horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div box where i have overflow-x:scroll and i want to alert() a message when user reach the end of the scroll.
Unfortunately i can't use document height like with the vertical scroll and find when user is at the bottom of the page,so i can't figure out if it's even possible to do.I have tried to compare the div.scrollLeft() with div.width but the width of the div is constant and it's not working.
So any idea how to know the end of the scroll even if the scroll changes with time?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<div style="width: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
```

jquery

```
 var scrolLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
 var windw = $(window).width();//important
 var documet = $(document).width();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollLeft() + windw == documet){
            console.log("right!");
        }
    });
```

**another**

```
<div id="scroll">
    <div id="width" style="width: 4000px">Scroll down!</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#scroll{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

jquery

```
var scrolLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
var windw = $('#scroll').width();//important
var documet = $('#width').width();
    $('#scroll').scroll(function() {
        if($('#scroll').scrollLeft() + windw == documet){
            console.log("right!");
        }
    });
```