# Detecting end of horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-scroll">
 <div class="inner">
  <a class="outer-arrow left"> <  </a>
  <a class="outer-arrow right"> > </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(function() {

    var lastLeftLocation = 0;
    var main_width = $('.inner').width();
    var offset = 100; 

    $('.outer-scroll').scroll(
        function(e)
        {               
             if (main_width - offset) {
                $(".outer-arrow.right").css({display: 'none'});
            }

            else
            {
                 $(".outer-arrow.right").css({display: 'block'});
            }



            lastLeftLocation     =    e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
        });

});
```

I'm trying to make it so when you've reached the furthest point of the scroll inner container, the right arrow disappears. I've googled, but can't seem to find any direction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery-find the end of horizontal scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839157/jquery-find-the-end-of-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 4):

It works in angular

```
<div class="container" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
   <div class="content">
       Some content 
   </div>
</div>


onScroll(event: Event) {
   if (event.target.scrollLeft + event.target.offsetWidth === event.target.scrollWidth){
      console.log('end');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.scrollwidth` in combination with `Element.scrollLeft` and `Element.clientWidth`:

```js
$('.outer-scroll').scroll(function(e) {
  var _this = this
  $(".outer-arrow.right", this).css({
    display: _this.scrollWidth === (_this.scrollLeft + _this.clientWidth) ? 'none' : 'block'
  });
}).scroll();
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
div div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
div a{position:fixed;}
a.left{left:0px;}
a.right{left:12px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-scroll">
  <div class="inner">
    <a class="outer-arrow left">
      < </a>
        <a class="outer-arrow right"> > </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my original post.

Comment: @Z0idberg check the edits. you can use it your own way.